# Loop through cells in range to find cells manually set to blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use the following code to loop through a range of cells, searching for cells that contain `=""`:

```
Sub ReplaceEmptyCells()
    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    Dim cell As Range

    i = "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    k = "#N/A"

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:AA51") 'Desired range to search through
        If cell.Value = i Then
            cell.Replace What:=i, Replacement:=k, MatchCase:=True
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

This value has been set manually on another sheet and the cells in question have been copied and pasted as a link (this was done so as to avoid the empty cells being converted to 0s after the paste, while maintaining 0s in the original data).

The intent is for the content of the "blank" cells on the new sheet to be "#N/A". Why doesn't the above Sub work?

Comment: `If cell.Formula= i Then`

Comment: and then just `Cell.Value = k`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Is this because the "blank" cells have been pasted as a link? Is there a work-around?

Comment: The debugger actually shows `k= ""`. Strange.

Comment: `If cell.Formula = i Then cell.Value = k` works for me.  I just replaced your whole If with that one line.

Comment: Still not working for me. Again, it must have something to do with the paste as link. The formula bar for the empty cells shows the linked cell: `='Sheet1'!M16`

Answer (score 0):

Why loop when you can just use:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C1:AA51").Replace  What:=i, Replacement:=k, Lookat:=xlWhole
```